# Handling OracleExceptions in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

AccountController

```
namespace IndividueleOpdracht.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Signup(SignupViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var accountModel = new AccountModel();

                try
                {
                    accountModel.Signup(model);

                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
                }
                catch (SignupException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("SignupError", e.Message);
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel used for the Sign up

```
namespace IndividueleOpdracht.ViewModels
{
    public class SignupViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul een naam in")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(16)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul een gebruikersnaam in")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul een email adres in")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vul een wachtwoord in")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*accountModel.Signup(model)* calls a repository.

This context method is called by the repository.

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace IndividueleOpdracht.DAL
{
    public class AccountContext : OracleContext
    {
        public void Insert(SignupViewModel account)
        {
            using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Account " +
                                      "(Id, Name, Username, Email, Password) " +
                                      "VALUES " +
                                      "(account_seq.NEXTVAL, :name, :username, :email, :password)";

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("name", account.Name));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("username", account.Username));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("email", account.Email));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("password", account.Password));

                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0) // Will throw a OracleException
                    {
                        throw new LoginException("Een of meer velden zijn niet correct ingevuld.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to handle Oracle Exceptions? Just add another catch to the try/catch, but then you are using data stuff inside the controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Handle exceptions where they occur.**

I would say the best place is inside the `AccountContext.Insert` method. There, and only there, you are in the context of the exception and your relationship with the database (why would your Account controller need to know there is an Oracle database after all?). Handle it there. I would recommend to catch the exception there, wrap it in something you can handle outside, and re-throw it.

Comment: Soo, whats the best way to do that? If i throw a new LoginException inside the catch, it wont catch inside the LoginException..

Comment: Then catch whatever you need in the controller, as long as it is not an `OracleException`.

Comment: Dumb me, i was trying to throw a LoginException and handle it inside a SignupException catch block. Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score -1):

I would respectfully disagree with the previous poster and instead suggest that you don't handle it (directly in your controller/DAL) at all.

I would suggest that you use the ability in ASP.net to display an appropriate error screen when an unhandled exception occurs and in the background log the unexpected error so that you can subsequently examine it. (I'm a fan of Elmah for these logging purposes: https://elmah.io/).

Unless you have a specific requirement (e.g. retry on DB failure), then I would suggest not littering your code with exception handling and instead handle any unexpected exceptions in a common place.

Comment: You never handle an Oracle exception in the UI. Instead you throw an exception that the application understands. You wrap the other exception in the inner exception.

Comment: I think never is a bit strong - it depends on your application.  Personally I'm just a fan of not catching exceptions unless I can handle them where caught.

Comment: I agree on your last sentence. You catch it if it makes sense. It does make sense to abstract the actual data access layer away in your exception handling. You don't want to tell the user `ORA-0XXXX`. You want to tell that table X can't be accessed because of a permission problem. The original exception must be captured for logging obviously.